# How reliable are URIs like /index.php/seo_path

Tags: php, url, server-configuration, pathinfo

I noticed, that sometimes (especially where mod_rewrite is not available) this path scheme is used:

```
http://host/path/index.php/clean_url_here
--------------------------^
```

This *seems* to work, at least in Apache, where `index.php` is called, and one can query the `/clean_url_here` part via `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`. PHP even [kind of advertises](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) this feature. Also, e.g., the [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com) framework uses this technique as default for their URLs.

*The question:* How reliable is the technique? Are there situations, where Apache doesn't call `index.php` but tries to resolve the path? What about lighttpd, nginx, IIS, AOLServer?

*A ServerFault question?* I think it's got more to do with using this feature inside PHP code. Therefore I ask here.

**Addendum:** As suggested by VolkerK, a reasonable extension to this question is: How can a programmer influence the existence of `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` on various server types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this a question which is equally suited for stackoverflow and serverfault. E.g. I as a developer can only tell you that pathinfo is as trustworthy as any user-input (which means it can contain virtually anything) and your script may or may not receive it depending on the webserver version and configuration:

Apache: [AcceptPathInfo](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo)
IIS: e.g. [AllowPathInfoForScriptMappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525840.aspx) and others
and so on and on...

But server admins possibly can tell you which settings you can expect "in the real world" and why those settings are preferred.
So the question becomes: How much influence do you (or the expected userbase) have on the server configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the Apache and IIS links. After a bit of Googling (based on the newly gained knowledge about AcceptPathInfo), I found a solution for nginx as well: http://kbeezie.com/view/php-self-path-nginx/

Answer (score 1):

[*AcceptPathInfo*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) needs to be enabled in order to have this working.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I'd say `PATH_INFO` *is* usually available in normal web hosting environments and server setups - even on IIS -  but on rare occasions, it is not. When building an application that is supposed to be deployable on as many platforms as possible, I would not trust path_info on a hard-coded level.

Whenever I can, I try to build a wrapper function `build_url()` that, depending on a configuration setting, uses either

- the raw URL `www.example.com/index.php?clean_url=clean_url_here`
- the path_info mechanism `www.example.com/index.php/clean_url`
- mod_rewrite `www.example.com/clean_url`

and use that in all URLs the application emits.

Comment: Abstraction is always a good idea, agreed. However, I'd like to specifically know about the PATH_INFO experiences and the availability of this feature.

Answer (score 0):

There might be naive scripts (auto-linking for example) that do not recognize this URL's format. Thereby decreasing the chance that links to your content will be created.
Since home-grown regular expression patterns are common for these tasks, the chance of failure is quite real.

Technically, those URLs are fine. SEO-wise, they are 'less perfect'.